# how to extract the words from a list to a new list?

Tags: python, list

I want to extract the words from the biggest number which is 3 with is love to the smallest number

```
[1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
```

the result will be:

```
['love','word','hello', 'hi','you']
```

Thanks for the help!

I have this code but I'm stuck because of error message `TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments`:

```
s="hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"


def f(s):
    all=s.split(',')
    print(all)
    uni=[]
    count=[]
    sorted=[]
    for word in all:
      if word not in uni :
        uni.append(word)
    print(uni)
   for word in uni:
    c=all.count(word)
    count.extend([c,word])
    print(count)
    count.sort(reversed)
    for w in count:
       sorted.append(w(1))
    return sorted

f(s)
print(sorted)
```

Comment: you want those words with the same frequency to be sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to pair the words the numbers and then sort it

```
>>> lst = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
>>> [word.strip() for _,word in sorted(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]), reverse=True)]
['love', 'word', 'hello', 'you', 'hi']
```

To retain the order for words with same frequency, you have to `zip` with `range` as follows

```
>>> [w.strip() for *_,w in sorted(zip(lst[::2], range(len(lst)//2, 0, -1), lst[1::2]), reverse=True)]
['love', 'word', 'hello', 'hi', 'you']
```

Comment: the word 'you' should be the last one

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
z = [w for _,w in sorted(zip(x[0::2],x[1::2]), reverse=True)]
print(z)
#[' love', ' word', 'hello', ' you', ' hi']
```

---

If the problem starts with `s`

```
from collections import Counter
s="hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"
slist = s.split(',')
sdict = dict(Counter(slist))
result = sorted(sdict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
result = [i[0] for i in result]
print(result) 
# [' love', ' word', 'hello', ' hi', ' you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not good. Don't put count and word in a flat list, but use tuples. Otherwise, all numbers would be sorted independently from the words.

`reverse` is a keyword-argument, which expects a boolean value.

```
def sort_words(text):
    words = text.split(',')
    unique_words = set(words)
    word_counts = []
    for word in unique_words:
        word_counts.append((words.count(word), word))
    word_counts.sort(reverse=True)
    sorted = []
    for count, word in word_counts:
        sorted.append(word)
    return sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

I first thought about converting your list to a dictionary, but best would be to create a list of tuples. Obviously, the elements in the array seem sorted.
Then sort and reverse the order and yiu will get your list

```
test = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']

new_test = [(test[x], test[x+1]) for x in range(0,len(test),2)]

new_test.sort()
new_test.reverse()
new_test

strings = []
for elem in new_test:
    strings.append(elem[1])
print(strings)

[' love', ' word', 'hello', ' you', ' hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not pythonic. If you have already counted the occurrences of the words, you may try

```
aa = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
cc = [v for c,v in sorted(zip(aa[0::2], aa[1::2]),reverse=True)]
print(cc)
```

If the input is a string as in your code, the following code works.

```
from collections import Counter
s="hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"

cnt = Counter()
for w in s.split(','):
  cnt[w.strip()] += 1

print(sorted(cnt, key=cnt.get, reverse=True))
```

Thank @Pynchia. Now the same thing can be achieved in two lines.

```
from collections import Counter
cnt=Counter(s.replace(',', '').split()) 
print(sorted(cnt, key=cnt.get, reverse=True))
```

Comment: Good idea to use Counter. But then, why not simplify things a bit and let Counter do its job: `c=Counter(s.split())
s = sorted(c.items(), key=lambda e:e[1], reverse=True)
out = [e[0] for e in s]`

Answer (score 0):

yet another solution, more idiomatic and a classic in grouping elements from an iterable

```
x = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
t = zip(*[iter(x)]*2)  # creates a seq of tuples with two consecutive elements each
s = sorted(t, reverse=True) # no need for a key
out = [e[1] for e in s]
print(out)
```

which gives

```
[' love', ' word', 'hello', ' hi', ' you']
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this beautiful solutions:

1) if you want to have your list:

```
l = [1, 'hello', 2, ' word', 3, ' love', 1, ' hi', 1, ' you']
l[1::2] = [e.strip() for e in l[1::2]]
print([w for _, w in sorted(sorted(zip(l[::2], l[1::2])), key = lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)])
```

output:

```
 ['love', 'word', 'hello', 'hi', 'you']
```

2) if you want to start from s:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "hello, word, word, love, love, love, hi, you"

print([w for w, _ in sorted(sorted(Counter(s.split(', ')).items()), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)])
```

output:

```
 ['love', 'word', 'hello', 'hi', 'you']
```